# Codingbat challenge: maxBlock

Tags: java, string

Given the task [maxBlock](https://codingbat.com/prob/p179479) from CodingBat:

Given a string, return the length of the largest “block” in the string. A block is a run of adjacent chars that are the same.

```
maxBlock("hoopla") → 2
maxBlock("abbCCCddBBBxx") → 3
maxBlock("") → 0
```

My solution passes all the tests except one:

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
  int maxBlock = 0;
  int currentBlock = 1;
  
  if (str.length() < 1) {
    return maxBlock;
  } else {
    maxBlock = 1;
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) ==  str.charAt(i+1)) {
      currentBlock++;
      if (currentBlock > maxBlock) {
        maxBlock = currentBlock;
        currentBlock = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return maxBlock;
}
```

What is the problem here? How could I fix it?
[image]

Comment: I suggest you run your program locally and add some debug System.println statements (or use the debugger) and try to figure it out.

Comment: (but as a hint: what about when you get a new largest block, but you aren't at the end of the block yet?)

Comment: you must set currentBlock = 0;  if chars are unequal and not like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not correctly resetting your `currentBlock` count. You need to reset the `currentBlock` to `1` if the following character is different from the current one. If not, you need to continue increasing `currentBlock`:

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
  int maxBlock = 0;
  int currentBlock = 1;
  
  if (str.length() < 1) {
    return maxBlock;
  } else {
    maxBlock = 1;
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) ==  str.charAt(i+1)) {
      currentBlock++;
      if (currentBlock > maxBlock) {
        maxBlock = currentBlock;
      }
    } else {
      currentBlock = 1;
    }
  }
  
  return maxBlock;
}
```

Comment: yes, but counting from 1 is stupid a little bit. count from 0 and return maxBlock+1 looks  clearer to me

Comment: @user184868 Agree. Besides that, there are more improvements that could be made, but wanted to keep my changes minimal as not to obfuscate what the issue was with the original code.

Answer (score 2):

Although I think @Robby Cornelissen and @Eskandar Abedini's solutions are definitely more viable than mine and closer to the original code, I would like to chip in to offer a different approach by using regex and a bit of coding logic.

The following regex looks for a match where a character reappears 0 or more times. This could be employed with the `results()` method of the `Matcher` class to extract the longest match found.

Here is a link to test the regex

https://regex101.com/r/OcMoQ9/1

##### Code Implementation

```
List<String> testCase = List.of("hoopla", "abbCCCddBBBxx", "", "xyz", "xxyz", "xyzz", "abbbcbbbxbbbx", "XXBBBbbxx", "XXBBBbbxxXXXX", "XX2222BBBbbXX2222");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)(\\1*)");
Matcher matcher;

for (String s : testCase) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    System.out.printf("%s => %d%n", s, matcher
            .results()
            .map(match -> match.group().length())
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Integer::intValue))
            .orElse(0));
}

//Or even simpliefied like so as @Holger has pointed out in the comments
for (String s : testCase) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    System.out.printf("%s => %d%n", s, matcher
            .results()
            .mapToInt(match -> match.group().length())
            .max()
            .orElse(0));
}
```

##### Link to Test the code

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rH7

##### Output

```
hoopla => 2
abbCCCddBBBxx => 3
 => 0
xyz => 1
xxyz => 2
xyzz => 2
abbbcbbbxbbbx => 3
XXBBBbbxx => 3
XXBBBbbxxXXXX => 4
XX2222BBBbbXX2222 => 4
```

Comment: You don’t need a construct like `Comparator.comparing(Integer::intValue)`, you can simply use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` for comparing `Integer` objects. However, even simpler is to use `.mapToInt(match -> match.group().length()) .max() .orElse(0)`

Answer (score 1):

This code is generated by [GitHub Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/) plugin for IntelliJ, you need just type `int maxBlock` then GitHub Copilot generates rest of the code:

```
private int maxBlock(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) return 0;
    int maxBlocks = 0;
    int currentBlocks = 0;
    char currentChar = s.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == currentChar) {
            currentBlocks++;
        } else {
            currentBlocks = 1;
            currentChar = s.charAt(i);
        }
        maxBlocks = Math.max(maxBlocks, currentBlocks);
    }
    return maxBlocks;
}
```

I only added `if (s == null || s.length() == 0) return 0;` to generated code.

Comment: Doesn't really explain to the op what the issue was